# How to have only one multi-select dropdown open at a time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have 2 dropdowns:

```
 <span id="span1">
        <div id="list2" class="dropdown-check-list">
            <select
          id="list2_items"  name="1"
        multiple
        class="selectpicker "
        title="Select">
                <option>1</option>

            </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


   </span>
  <span id="span2" >
    <select class="form-dropdown" name="2" id="2" required>
        <option value=""> Select</option>
        <option value="1"> 1</option>
    </select>
  </span>
```

Here's the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jtb341va/2/)
Now I only want one drop down to open at a time, but what happens is both remain opened together.

I tried various solution but none work on select and bootstrap multi select, if someone could please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: There's just one dropdown

Comment: Im sorry made the changes

Answer (score 0):

You can add class to all select elements and on click select box you can collapse all other select boxes and open the selected box.

for example,

```
<select class="selectBox" id="box_1" onclick="openBox('box_1')">
<select class="selectBox" id="box_2" onclick="openBox('box_2')">
<select class="selectBox" id="box_3" onclick="openBox('box_3')">

// Javascript function
function openBox(id){
    $('.selectBox').collapse
    $('#'+id).expand
}
```